# Can we send the api endpoint urls for scan without its payload and http method?

Tags: security, burp

I am using burp rest native api to performscan reques
Can we send the api endpoint urls for scan without its payload and http method?
Will it automatically scan with all the http method and payload?

Answer (score 1):

Burp will just run blind **get** requests at these